# How do I prevent Tkinter from crashing when my code loses internet

Tags: tkinter, freeze, weather-api, openweathermap, magic-mirror

A few months ago I wrote a magic mirror code in tkinter.  When I made it, it was able to continue without problems. Due to drive issues, I'm not sure that this my final product (I've also cut the Calendar out for this), but regardless now it  does not generally respond, when I cut the internet.  How can I make it run smoothly? I realize it's a fairly large piece and appreciate any help I can get.

```
""" MagicMirror
    Includes clock, and weather
"""

from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from httplib2 import Http
import json
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from platform import system
import requests
from tkinter import *


class GlobalVars:
    def __init__(self, is_Celcius, postalCode):
        self.celcius = is_Celcius
        self.zipCode = postalCode


#----------time----------
#delete seconds later


class Clock(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = "black")

        self.time = ""
        self.day = ""
        self.time_Label = Label(self, text = self.time, font =('Helvetica', 70, "bold"), fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.time_Label.pack(anchor = E)
        self.day_Label = Label(self, text = self.day, font = ("Helvetica", 20, "italic"), fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.day_Label.pack(side = RIGHT, anchor = E)
        self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        self.time_Label.config(text = str(datetime.now())[11:19])
        date = str(datetime.now())
        currentDay = calendar.day_name[datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now())[:10], "%Y-%m-%d").weekday()]\
        + ", " + calendar.month_name[int(date[5:7])] + " " + date[8:10]
        if self.day != currentDay:
            self.day = currentDay
            self.day_Label.config(text = self.day)
        print("Clock check")
        self.time_Label.after(1000, self.tick)


#--------weather---------


# allow for easy installment of multiple cities (through list of zipCodes?)
class Weather(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, celc, zipCode):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = "black")
        self.locations = list()

        if system() == "Darwin":  # MAC
            self.path = "./icons/"
        elif system() == "Linux":
            self.path = "/home/pi/Documents/MagicMirror_testing/icons/"
        else:  # PC
            self.path = "D:\MPZinke\Drive\Workspace\MagicMirror\icons\\"
        self.pathDict = {"broken clouds" : "cloudy.jpg", "error" : "error.jpg", "few clouds" : "partCloudy.jpg", "foggy" : "foggy.jpg", 
                         "icey" : "icey.jpg", "light rain" : "rain.jpg", "mist" : "foggy.jpg", "overcast clouds" : "cloudy.jpg", 
                         "scattered clouds" : "partCloudy.jpg", "rain" : "rain.jpg", "scattered clouds" : "partCloudy.jpg", 
                         "snow" : "snow.jpg", "clear sky" : "sunny.jpg", "tStorms" : "tStorms.jpg", "wind" : "windy.jpg"}

        for loc in zipCode:
            self.locations.append(Location(self, celc, loc))
        self.weatherLoop()


    def weatherLoop(self):
        self.weatherIcons = list()
        for i in range(len(self.locations)):
            self.locations[i].update()

            try: path = self.path + self.pathDict[self.locations[i].weather[0]]
            except:  # handles unkown dictionary entries
                path = self.path + self.pathDict["error"]
                print(self.locations[i].weather[0])

            self.weatherIcons.append(PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(path)))
            self.locations[i].labels[0].config(image = self.weatherIcons[i])

            self.locations[i].labels[4].pack(side = TOP, anchor = NW)
            self.locations[i].currentFrame.pack(side = TOP, anchor = NW)
            orientation = [LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, TOP]
            for j in range(len(self.locations[i].labels)-1):
                self.locations[i].labels[j].pack(side = orientation[j], anchor = NW)    

        print("Weather check")
        self.after(5000, self.weatherLoop)




class Location(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, celc, zipCode):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = "black")
        self.zipCode = str(zipCode)
        self.celc = celc

        self.labels = []
        self.currentFrame = Frame(parent, background = "black")

        parents = (self.currentFrame, self.currentFrame, parent, parent, parent)
        for i in parents:
            self.labels.append(Label(i, bg = "black", anchor = NW))

    def update(self):
        self.weather = organizeWeather(self.celc, self.zipCode)
        tempChar = "° F"
        if self.celc: tempChar = "° C"

        self.labels[1].config(text = self.weather[1] + tempChar, font = ("Helvetica", 45, "bold"), fg = "white")
        self.labels[2].config(text = "High: " + self.weather[2] + tempChar, font = ("Helvetica", 20, "bold"), fg = "white")
        self.labels[3].config(text = "Low: " + self.weather[3] + tempChar, font = ("Helvetica", 20, "bold"), fg = "white")
        self.labels[4].config(text = self.weather[4], font = ("Helvetica", 30, "underline"), fg = "white")  


#--------function--------


def getWeather(zipCode):
    address = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipCode + "&appid=556f1331999ad8f3fedec7ba906ebb54"
    try: 
        weatherData = requests.get(address, timeout=6.0).json()
    except requests.ConnectionError: 
        weatherData = None
        print("Could not get weather", datetime.today())
    return weatherData


def organizeWeather(celc, zipCode):
    temp = []
    data = getWeather(zipCode)
    print(zipCode)
    if data:
        temp.append(data["weather"][0]["description"])  # (ie clear, cloudy, etc)
        temp.append(toCelcius(celc, data["main"]["temp"]))  # current temp
        temp.append(toCelcius(celc, data["main"]["temp_max"]))  # high
        temp.append(toCelcius(celc, data["main"]["temp_min"]))  # low
        temp.append(data["name"])
        return temp
    return ["error", "", "", "", ""]


def toCelcius(celcius, temp):
    temp = temp - 273.15
    if not celcius:
        temp = temp * 1.8 + 32
    return str(int(temp))



class TextWidget(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, words):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = "black")

        self.title1 = Label(self, text = words, font = ("Helvetica", 20, "bold"), fg = "white", bg = "black")
        self.title1.pack(side = LEFT, anchor = E)


class Startscreen:
    def __init__(self):
        # setup window
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("MagicMirror")
        self.tk.configure(background = 'black')
        self.tk.geometry('1024x786')
        self.tk.resizable(500, 500)  # *

        self.constants = GlobalVars(True, ["77077"])

        # assign frames
        self.leftTop = Frame(self.tk, background = "black", width=500, height=500)
        self.rightTop = Frame(self.tk, background = "black", width=350, height=100)
        self.rightBottom = Frame(self.tk, background = "black", width=150, height=650)
        self.leftTop.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y, expand = NO)
        self.rightTop.pack(side = TOP, expand = NO, anchor = NE)
        self.rightBottom.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y, expand = NO)

        # clock
        self.clock = Clock(self.rightTop)
        self.clock.pack(side = RIGHT, anchor = N, padx = 10, pady = 10, expand = NO)

        # weather
        self.weather = Weather(self.leftTop, self.constants.celcius, self.constants.zipCode)
        self.weather.pack(side = LEFT, anchor = NW)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Startscreen()
    window.tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: At  onepoint you say it doesn’t respond, at another point you say it crashes. Those usually mean two different things. Can you clarify?

Comment: So when I hover the cursor over the tkinter window it is the loading/processing cursor and the window does not update. In terminal around about every minute or so it will show what is printed from the except and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep checking for internet using the following and then, you can execute the code, if you have internet. If not, you can let the user know that there is no connection.

```
import socket
REMOTE_SERVER = "www.google.com"
def is_connected(hostname):
  try:
    host = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    return True
  except:
     pass
  return False
is_connected(REMOTE_SERVER)
```

Comment: That didn't quite work.  After running just the function separately, it looks like my computer does not accept timeout arguments, so regardless of how long I set it to time out, it goes on for longer than it should.  I'm currently running python 3.6.2 and will see if 3.7.0 changes anything.

Comment: I added 3.7.0 and both your solution and my old program work now.  I had some trouble installing a few wheels (SciPy, SKLearn, etc) but luckily I don't need them for this purpose.  Thank you!